# Why is $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B) \not\subset \mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I had a question in my 11th grade Mathematics book:

> Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B) \not\subset \mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$.

I did a proof for why $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B) \subset \mathcal{P}(A)\cup P(B)$

Which step in the following proof is wrong?

**Proof**

Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of a set $Y$
Let $Y$ be an element of $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$
So, $Y \subset (A\cup B)$
So, $y \in (A\cup B)$
So, $y \in A$ or $y ∈ B$
So, $Y \subset A$ or $Y \subset B$
So, $Y \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $Y ∈ \mathcal{P}(B)$
So, $Y \in \mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$
And thus:  every element of $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup P(B)$
So, $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B) \subset \mathcal{P}(A)\cup P(B)$

I suspect a mistake in the 6th line but I just wanted confirmation.

Thank You...

Comment: The 6th line is wrong. What you have shown is that an arbitrary $y\in Y$ is in $A$ or is in $B$ but this doesn't mean ALL $y\in Y$ satisfy this for same set $A$ or $B$. You might have some $y\in Y$ who are in $A$ and some $y\in Y$ who are in $B$

Comment: Your mistake is indeed on the sixth line. You can't conclude that because from the previous line all you know is that $y$ is in $A$ or $B$ but that says nothing about a different element and where it belongs. And you can easily construct a counter example. Let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $\{a, b\} \in P(A\cup B) $. (From this example, you can glean that what you said is true if and only if at least one of $A$ and $B$ is empty.)

Comment: Is $P(A)$ a power set or a probability or something else?

Comment: @Henry it's the powerset

Comment: Thanks TSF, Cameron Williams, it was helpful :)

Comment: For finite sets:   $$$$$\operatorname{card}\left(\mathcal P(A\cup B)\right)=2^{\operatorname{card}A+\operatorname{card}B-\operatorname{card}(A\cap B)}$
  $\operatorname{card}\left(\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)\right)=2^{\operatorname{card} A}+2^{\operatorname{card}B}-2^{\operatorname{card}\left(\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P( B)\right)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th line is wrong. What you have shown is that an arbitrary $y\in Y$ is in $A$ or is in $B$ but this doesn't mean ALL $y\in Y$ satisfy this for same set $A$ or $B$. You might have some $y\in Y$ who are in $A$ and some $y'\in Y$ who are in $B$. Then, $Y$ is not an element of $P(A)$ or of $P(B)$ but is an element of of $P(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Sir, you probably mean that $Y$ is not an $element$ of $P(A)$ or $P(B)$. You have mentioned $subset$ instead.

Comment: @VishalAgarwal, changed now...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu Yeah.